# What happens when you have two connected network interfaces?

Tags: macos, network

I have two connected network interfaces, ethernet and WLAN.  How does OSX handle traffic in this situation? When outgoing messages are sent which interface are they sent from? If I use tools such as Logmein.com, which interface does it connect through?

Comment: It depends a bit on what networks each adapter is on and how the routing tables are set up. Can we assume both interfaces are on the same network and the  gateway to the internet is common to both interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is for older OSX systems - macOS Ventura (I think ) changed System Preferences to System Settings and altered the work flow to get to the Service Order dialog box.

It depends on the service order set in System Preferences->Network. The first one that has a route to the requested endpoint will be used.

Click on the wheel icon at the bottom left and choose `Set Service Order...`. Then drag the items into the required order.

This is the order on m machine which I do not think I have altered.

[image: Service Order Pop up]

Comment: @GregDubicki - the answer still works for many people who are still on old versions of OSX. You should make a new answer - and edit at the top of this answer that this allies to pre-Ventura and for modern macOS see your answer.

Comment: But it's the same answer, just an updated screenshot...

Comment: Note quite - the steps to get there do differ - Settings rather than preference, button on the loft or right and what the button looks like